# Проверка сессии Telethon

Tags: python, telethon

как в telethon можно сделать проверку сессии? Мне нужно, чтобы питон проверял сессию, и если она не работает, то скрипт останавливался, а не предлагал мне авторизоваться. Смотрел в документации, ничего подобного не нашел.

Answer (score 0):

Как оказалось, это очень легко, а искал я плохо :)
Но вдруг кому-то тоже понадобится

```
await client.connect()
if not await client.is_user_authorized():
    print("Ошибка авторазации")
    return
```